# How to get the code changes just from the PR link?

Tags: git, github

My former colleague, Adam, raised a Pull Request from a branch in his forked repository to the main repository. Now he has left the organisation and this PR got auto closed saying `Adam closed this by deleting the head repository`

Now I need these code changes to finish this task. How can I pull these changes into my local?

I tried `git pull origin pull/939/head`, `git fetch origin pull/$ID/head:$BRANCHNAME`, but I get error `fatal: couldn't find remote ref` .

Please provide me a way to get the changes.

Comment: GitHub keeps an audit log of all ref updates. It might be possible to find the ref from the deleted PR somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not merge in that PR then it is gone for good, Adam deleted the source code on his repo on his branch, he actually deleted his whole repo. The PR link just compares the codes on the 2 repos/branches so you can not get code from the PR object itself.

Only thing you could do is ask Adam if he still has the code on his machine and ask him to push it back to his github repo (not sure but PR might reopen and you could merge) or send the code by email it to you.

In a company environment all employees should work on the main repo by opening their own branches and PR-ing from there to the main branch (or whatever you integration branch is), so when you need to kick somebody you just remove their permission from the repo managed by the company. Also [disable forking](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/managing-the-forking-policy-for-your-repository) to further enforce this workflow.

Comment: Can't we do something with the PR link? Any way to fetch the changes and add them to local codebase?

Comment: @LightYagami No, the PR as it name suggests is just a request to pull changes from the source (base) branch to the target branch. That source branch is where the code is, so if it is deleted then it is gone. So technically you can't really do much more, only legally because the former employee should have had handed over all the work that was done during his employment, because that was the work that he was essentially paid for. So either ask Adam politely to hand over the code it it didn't work then consult your legal team what to do legally.

Comment: On the PR, is shows some option like `gh pr checkout 8123`. Is that of any use?

Comment: `gh pr checkout 8123` won't be of any use here because *the source repo is gone*.